# II law of thermodynamics & polytropic process

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, ideal-gas

The polytropic process is defined as such that $pV^m=A$, where $A$ is a constant. Generally, the change in entropy is
$$\Delta S=nR \ln \frac{V}{V_0}+nC_V\ln \frac{T}{T_0}.$$
Using $pV=nRT$ and $pV^m=A$ we get $T=\frac{AV^{1-m}}{nR}$. Substituting into previous equation we obtain:
$$\Delta S=(\gamma -m)C_Vn\ln \frac{V}{V_0},$$
which is the formula for $\Delta S$ in polytropic process and $\gamma=C_p/C_V$. According to Wikipedia, for $m < 0$ II law of thermodynamics would be violated. The problem is, I can't really see why it would be - the entropy is positive and everything seems fine...

Comment: I don't see any reason either.

Comment: @ChetMiller. On the Wikipedia page, it says "Negative exponents reflect a process where work and heat flow simultaneously in or out of the system. In the absence of forces except pressure, such a spontaneous process is not allowed by the second law of thermodynamics..."  So there, it is talking about *spontaneous* processes. Clearly, this system cannot be isolated from its environment, because volume and pressure changing together necessarily implies that heat and work flows are in opposite directions....

Comment: ...Perhaps the answer, then, is that it's possible to show that the change in entropy of the environment forces the total entropy to decrease, meaning that the entropy goes down in an isolate system.

Comment: My understanding is that a polytropic process, by definition, is not spontaneous (i.e., it is reversible).

Answer (score 1):

If you decrease the pressure *p* in the polytropic process, the volume *V* of the system will be reduced too to fulfill the equality. Therefore the relation between the final and the initial volumes will be less than 1, and the change of the entropy will be negative.

Comment: But the change in entropy of a gas during some process can be negative, as long as there is a corresponding change in entropy elsewhere.

Comment: You are right about the total entropy.  However, why can't we consider that a system is closed?